# how to drag the view in react native

Tags: react-native

I have an example code I put it on below ,this example show the circle to drag another location

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  PanResponder,
  Animated
} from "react-native";

export default class Draggable extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY()
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Add a listener for the delta value change
    this._val = { x:0, y:0 }
    this.state.pan.addListener((value) => this._val = value);
    // Initialize PanResponder with move handling
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gesture) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y }
      ])
      // adjusting delta value
      this.state.pan.setValue({ x:0, y:0})
    });
  }

  render() {
    const panStyle = {
      transform: this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()
    }
    return (
        <Animated.View
          {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
          style={[panStyle, styles.circle]}
        />
    );
  }
}

let CIRCLE_RADIUS = 30;
let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
    backgroundColor: "skyblue",
    width: CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2,
    height: CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2,
    borderRadius: CIRCLE_RADIUS
  }
});
```

this code the circle to the drag but I have drag another location it goes on the starting location so have to set the current location value so please tell me